# Crossorigin doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cors

React keep me saying Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/users. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

The strange think it worked to me and it stopped working without any change to the controller code...

UserController.java

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private User findOne(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId) {
    return userService.findOne(userId);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
private List<User> findAll() {
    return userService.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
private User create(@RequestBody User user) {
    user.setId(null); // To ensure we create instead of update
    return userService.save(user);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
private User update(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId, @RequestBody User user) {
    user.setId(userId); // To ensure we update instead of create
    return userService.save(user);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
private void delete(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId) {
    final User user = userService.findOne(userId);
    userService.delete(user);
}
}
```

and this is my fetch on React

```
 fetch('http://localhost:8080/users', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
}).then(response => { return response.json();
}).then(data => {
  this.setState({users:data});
});
}
```

Any reason why it stopped working suddenly?

edit:

I tried making a clean new maven project and copied all packages into the new project and now it works, but I still don't know why it stopped work, the code is the same and now its working.

Comment: For spring @CrossOrigin there is ny default a maxAge of 30 minutes , try to increase that

Comment: Didn't work me, I made a new maven project and copied all the filed and now it works, all the code is the same so I really don't know what happened, I'm gonna edit the main post

Comment: Did you change your spring version or something like that ?

Comment: No, I used the same maven config

Comment: In react , earlier you used to usr proxy and now you are using complete path in fetch api , is it so ?

Comment: I used both times complete path, before and after CORS stopped working.

Comment: Can you please the post the complete error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Spring Security** and want CORS globally in your project then try to add it to the configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    httpSecurity
            .cors()
            .and()
            ........ other config

}
```

But before that try the following approaches. To apply **CORS** on class level use it like this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://domain2.com", maxAge = 3600)
@Controller
public class SomeController{

}
```

or use it in method level like this:

```
@CrossOrigin("http://example.com")
@RequestMapping("/some")
public Account retrieve() {
    // ...
}
```

**OR**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping("/some")
public Account retrieve() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: When I use @CrossOrigin on each function instead of on top of the class, it works again.  thanks

Comment: What is the difference between applying @CrossOrigin on class level and method level in your case so it works on method level but doesn't work on class level?

Comment: @Clay If you add crossOrigin in the class level then it will apply to each and every mapping declared inside that class.

Comment: @Sam I know, but in JoseCarlosPB's case, what is the difference so it didn't work on class level but works on method level? Because of the OPTIONS request doesn't contain the appropriate headers when CrossOrigin applied on class level?

Comment: @Clay The @CrossOrigin annotation that Jose wrote was not having `origins = "*"`. If you go into the implementation of CrossOrigin then you would see that there's no default value for that. So it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this annotation

```
@CrossOrigin(value = "*")
```

it worked at method level, **not class level**

After some trial and error, this is what worked at class level for me:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).